# How to set static external IP on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-devops

I have an EC2 instance in private subnet and want to set fixed external IP address to allow access from server outside of AWS to EC2 instance. When I assign Elastic IP, my external address differs from this Elastic IP. I check my external IP with

```
curl https://icanhazip.com
```

How can I set fixed external IP for EC2 instance?

Comment: Why do you need it to be private?

Comment: If you use NAT, all traffic will go through NAT. Elastic IP has no role in that.

Comment: Why do you want to give a public IP address to an instance in a Private Subnet?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I already have instance in private subnet and now I have a task to make it publicly accessible. Not moving instance to another subnet seems easier, isn't it?

Comment: @Marcin thanks. And what if I move instance to public subnet? Will it fix my issue?

Comment: An instance in a public subnet can be assigned a public IP address on launch, but this address will change if the instance is stopped and started. You can instead assign it an Elastic IP address, which will remain with the instance until you 'return' the Elastic IP address. Being in a public subnet, it will also be accessible to the Internet, so the other server can connect to it.

Comment: Please note that you cannot "move an instance" to another subnet -- you could launch a new instance instead. If you particularly need to retain everything on the current instance, create an AMI of the instance and then launch the new instance from that AMI (and in the public subnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You have a **private subnet** with an Amazon EC2 instance
- You have a **public subnet** with a NAT Gateway
- The **Route Table** on the private subnet directs Internet-bound traffic to the NAT Gateway

When the private instance tries to access the Internet, **requests will be sent via the NAT Gateway**. The NAT Gateway will forward these requests to the Internet. The traffic will appear to come from the public IP address associated with the NAT Gateway.

Assigning a public IP address to an EC2 instance in a private subnet **does nothing** -- no traffic will ever 'use' that public IP address because the instance is unable to directly connect to the Internet Gateway.

Comment: ok, I get it. If I move instance to public subnet - will it fix my issue?